# taking school courses efficiently

Tags: optimization, scheduling

I want design algorithm that allows a student to take important courses quickly up until graduation. no time, room number,  professors needed here. just my selected courses I know will allow me to graduate but how best to take them based on prerequisites. the student can decide how many courses to take a semester. And, you cant take a course's prerequisite and itself 
eg cs101 cs102 201 but cs201 cant be taken in the first semester because i have to take its prerequisites first. Additionally prequisites can be  such that 101 and 102 or 101 and 104 are possible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 201. We could also have 101 or 106 and 102 or 105 ossible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 202.

any suggestions and how to go about it. Trees, graph adjacency list

I was thinking topological sort will give a valid ordering but i think i would ran into trouble when placing them in across semesters because topological sort order them linearly eg cs101 cs102 201 but cs201 cant be taken in the first semester because i have to take its prerequisites first. And what about if we have cs 103 cs104 cs202. cs103 and 104 have nothing to do with cs101 102

Comment: I’m not sure whether you are interested in an algorithm you can apply to many problems or whether you want a particular instance of the problem solved. Assuming the latter, the first thing I would try is roughly enumerating how many possible orderings there are for your particular problem. You may have fewer meaningfully different choices than you think.

Comment: I you familiar with the concept of longest paths in DAGs?

Comment: @Ryan1729 the latter. How do i  roughly enumerate. I was thinking topological sort will give a valid ordering but i think i would ran into trouble when placing them in across semesters because topological sort order them linearly

Comment: @YuvalFilmus no, but i know of shortest paths and i was thinking to just reverse the condition on the weights

Comment: You might be looking for the longest path in the dependency DAG.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but that makes it a linear path. eg cs101 cs102 201 but cs201 cant be taken in the first semester. And what about if we have cs 103 cs104 cs202. cs103 and 104 have nothing to do with cs101 102

Comment: Perhaps it’s best if you defined your problem in more detail.

Comment: Your problem is unclear as states, since there are unstated assumptions. For example, why can't cs201 be taken in the first semester? How do we know? What, exactly, are the constraints? The first step to solving a problem is formulating it. Please define your problem in full detail.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i edited the question now

Comment: @YuvalFilmus please i would very much appreciate your feedback again

Comment: You still haven't defined your problem clearly enough. As far as I understand, here is your problem. Each course $x$ is associated with some monotone condition $P_x$. You want to arrange the courses into sets $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ such that for each $x \in S_i$, the condition $P_x$ is satisfied by the courses in $S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_{i-1}$ (stated a bit informally). You want to minimize the length of the sequence, subject to it containing all courses (or perhaps you have a different condition in mind).

Comment: Only you can define your problem. In particular, you should explain what the possible conditions $P_x$ are, and what are the requirements for graduation, that is, what courses you have to take in order to graduate (do you really have to take all of them?). Also, if there are any other constraints (such as, not all courses are available every semester), you must let us know. We can't read your mind!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes you have to take all the courses, the assumption is the student knows what courses to take to graduate and every course is available every semester. you defined the problem well enough.  eg S_2 could be satisfied by either  P_i and P_j or P_k and P_l in this case which group is best to take to satisfy S_2. In plain words,  prequisites can be such that (101 and 102) or (101 and 104) are possible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 201. We could also have (101 or 106) and (102 or 105) possible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 202

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Im not used to writing that way, ill learn

Answer (score 2):

Form a directed graph of dependencies, with an edge $x\to y$ if course $x$ is a prerequisite for course $y$.  Use [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm) to topologically sort the graph.  In particular, in each semester, you take all courses with indegree 0 (i.e., all courses where you've satisfied all prerequisites), then delete those courses from the graph.

This assumes there is no limit on the number of courses you can take in each semester.  Under that condition, it will let you complete your degree in the minimum number of semesters, in an order that respects the prerequisites.

If there is a limit on the number of courses you can take in a semester, the problem is more challenging.    This algorithm will find an order you can take your courses to get your degree, in an order that respects the prerequisites, but it is not necessarily the minimal number of semesters.  If you're in that situation, the best solution may depend on the number of courses you have and whether this is a practical problem you want to solve in real life or a theoretical problem where you care about worst-case asymptotic running time.

Comment: So after i get the first 4 courses with 0 indegree, i could perform the longest dependency path among them then chooses the longest as the one with most priority?

Comment: @pilolo, no need to compute the longest dependency path explicitly.  Kahn's algorithm is a lot simpler than that -- read the link I shared.  See edited answer.

Comment: I took a look at the algorithm and it seems appropriate, thanks. do i need to handle these cases separately?  prequisites can be such that (101 and 102) or (101 and 104) are possible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 201. We could also have (101 or 106) and (102 or 105) possible choices to take as prerequisites to a course 202.